# Azure KeyVault Access Policies - Adding App Service using Powershell and VSTS

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have a Azure Key Vault in which I want to add access policies for my MSI enabled App Service using powershell.

Using portal it's straightforward. As you can see below, I am searching by my app service name and I see app service and app registrations both.

[image]

in above example I selected app service directly without registrating it in Azure AD and it's working awesome.

I just need guidance to do the same using Azure Powershell(which will run VSTS SPN).

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: When I tried from my side, I could see only the registered App.wondering how could you see the app service itself in here !

Comment: So your Azure Powershell will be running inside VSTS? VSTS will need an MSI. I don't think it has one though. For example, when you run powershell in Azure Automation or inside a VM, you get an MSI. Not so sure about VSTS

Comment: Maybe this will help - the Azure CLI bit. Please try it out and confirm if it works because I'm probably going to also have to do this in the next month or so http://blog.jstroheker.com/2016/10/11/SPNAzure/

Comment: or this.... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/03/31/granular-vststfs-deployment-privileges-using-service-principals/ there seem to be a lot of guides

Comment: and here's the official one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts

Comment: What do you mean selected app service without registrating it in Azure AD? How did you create this app? Where the app service registered? As far as I know the app should be register to the AAD.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $valutName -UserPrincipalName 'PattiFuller@contoso.com' -PermissionsToKeys create,import,delete,list -PermissionsToSecrets set,delete -PassThru
```

Make sure you have logged in from the PowerShell and selected the resource group where the resource exists before you run the command.

Refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azurermps-6.7.0) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question about an app service which is not registered in AD, can we add the access policies for that in KV?

Comment: I am really not sure about the active directory registration. You could try running that and see if there's an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the the `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` command but with **ObjectId** parameter.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName my-keyvault -ResourceGroupName my-resource-group -ObjectId 15faf32d-146a-4985-a315-640527b6c489 -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

Bear in mind that MSI apps are registered as Enterprise Apps.

EDIT: Curious, what are you trying to achieve?